# How to sort with less precision on keys with Thrust library

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust, radix-sort

I have a set of integer values and I want to sort them using Thrust. Is there a possiblity for using only some high bits/low bits in this sorting. If possible I do not want to use user defined comparator, because it changes the used algorithm from radix-sort to merge-sort and increases elapsed time quite much.

I think when all the numbers have the same value on a bit, the bit is skipped while sorting, so is it feasible to use the lowest possible bit number and hope it will be sufficient. (ie: for 5 bits using char with 8 bits and setting upper 3 bits to 0)

Example:

```
sort<4, 0>(myvector.begin(), myvector.end())
sort<4, 1>(myvector.begin(), myvector.end())
```

sort using only 4 bits, high or low..

Something similar to
http://www.moderngpu.com/sort/mgpusort.html

Comment: There's no explicit way to do this and it generally isn't necessary. `thrust::sort`'s radix sort will inspect the data and omit superfluous passes amidst zeroed bits.

Comment: Yes, when I sort the vectors, I get different elapsed time values according the contained values. Even though the contained values are the same, when the type of the container is int, short or byte, then I also get different elapsed time values. It increases just a bit when the numbers are signed. But as you said, it omits bits with all zero.

Comment: I think the comment of @JaredHoberock is an adequate answer. If you convert your comment to answer I can specify it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thrust's interface abstracts away algorithm implementation details such as the fact that one of the current sorting strategies is a radix sort. Due to the possibility that the underlying sort implementation could change from version to version, backend to backend, or even invocation to invocation, there is no way for the user to communicate the number of bits to sort.

Fortunately, such explicit information generally isn't necessary. When appropriate, Thrust's current sorting implementation will inspect the sorting keys and omit superfluous computation amidst zeroed bits.

Answer (score 0):

<del>How about using transformer_iterator? 
Here is a short example (sort by first bit) and you can write your own unary function for your purpose.</del>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

using namespace std;
struct and_func : public thrust::unary_function<int,int>
{
    __host__ __device__
        int operator()(int x)
        {
            return 8&x;
        }
};
int main()
{
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec(4);
    d_vec[0] = 10;
    d_vec[1] = 8;
    d_vec[2] = 12;
    d_vec[3] = 1;
    thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_vec.begin(), and_func()),
                 thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_vec.end(), and_func()),
                 d_vec.begin());
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout<<d_vec[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, `thrust::sort` won't work with `transform_iterator`. `transform_iterator` typically isn't mutable.

Comment: In fact I do divide the values by power of two, or cast them to simpler types before sorting... My initial values are floating point values, and I do scale them and convert to short types. I am not sure converting floating point values to short types and sorting them is an over-optimization attempt or not..

Comment: Thanks @JaredHoberock to point out my error, I've never noticed this before.